# MS Bot Framework 4.x SDK. How can I send raw JSON to a facebook messenger channel using C#

Tags: c#, botframework, facebook-messenger-bot

You really need to be able to send raw json at facebook to take advantage of all of the facebook messenger features but I see no way to do that in the MS bot SDK.  (version 4).  Here is what I think should work, but no luck.  If I set the Text property of a reply activity it just shows up as text on messenger (as expected).  If I set the ChannelData property with a string no exceptions are thrown but facebook messenger shows no response message.  Given what a huge platform FB Messenger is you would think this was a priority in the SDK but I see nothing about it.

if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)

```
        {
            try
            {
                if((turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channel.Channels.Facebook)|| (turnContext.Activity.ChannelId == Channel.Channels.Emulator))
                {
                    string rsp = "{\"attachment\":{\"type\":\"template\",\"payload\":{\"template_type\":\"button\",\"text\":\"What do you want to do next?\",\"buttons\":[" +
      "{\"type\":\"web_url\",\"url\":\"https://www.messenger.com\",\"title\":\"Visit Messenger\"}]}}}";

                    Activity reply = turnContext.Activity.CreateReply();
                    _logger.LogInformation(rsp);

                    //reply.Text = rsp;  // display message as actual message to messenger
                    // reply.ChannelData = rsp; // fails request finishes on the MS bot service side, but nothing at all shows on messenger

                    reply.ChannelData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rsp); // WORKS!
                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply);
```

.... // IN MY ORIGINAL POST THERE WAS AN ERROR IN THE JSON STRING and I got the full answer a minute later... see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

My bad on this. The original post had an error in the rsp string but I also took a look at the sdk source and realized they wanted an object at ChannelData, not a string.... so I deserialized it and stuffed the object to channeldata and it started working. Few posts on this in SDK version 4 so hoping this helps someone. My wall needs some repair after me pounding my head against it all day. – Fred Covely just now